# Yii - Import / Export Excel

Tags: php, excel, yii, import, export

I want to know if there is an extension or anything to import and export in Yii.

Basically, I wanna save employeers to a database. But, when the user want to save, for example, 100 employers, he / she can do it importing an excel file.

Is there a library or any extension that can do that?

Please, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this extension
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpexcel/ 
or 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiiexcel/

and to read the excel file. You can use this extension

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/php-excel-reader/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and if results, i'll let you know.